# Fixing the [run] tag

Tags: discussion, support, retag-request

[run](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/run)

It's often about the Windows run dialog, and often it isn't. Therefore it's pretty useless.

Answer (score 3):

- Retag to [run-dialog](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/run-dialog) (alternative suggestions welcome) when related to the Windows *Run* dialog, set a tag wiki.
- Remove from all others (i.e. moderator-delete the tag), unless a good alternative already exists.